# display the output of math.max and math.min

Tags: reactjs, function, math, return, dataset

I want to display the findMax() output in a div but im facing this problem :

'findMax' is not defined  no-undef
, 'dataset' is not defined  no-undef

Someone suggested that I need to use useState but I'm not sure how to make it work , I would appreciate any help !

```
const pricedata = {
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: "#0000",
      barPercentage: 2,
      barThickness: 5,
      data: [1, 10, 30, 7, 42, 12],
      label: "Update in prices",
      maxBarThickness: 10
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: "#0000",
      barPercentage: 2,
      barThickness: 5,
      data: [11, 70, 18, 17, 24, 12],
      label: "Update in prices",
      maxBarThickness: 10
    }
  ]
};

function findMax(PRICES) {
  if (!PRICES) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Math.max(...PRICES);
}

pricedata.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
  dataset.maxPrice = findMax(dataset.data);
});

pricedata.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
  console.log('max price is', dataset.maxPrice);
});


return (
 <div>{findMax(dataset.data)}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'dataset' variable at the root level of the code. The `pricedata` variable contains an array called `datasets`. In your code when you call map, it loops over all the datasets - calling each individual one `dataset`. That variable name is only "scoped" to be within the map() function.

You can build the DIVs inside a map like this:

```
// call your findMax() on each element
const divs = pricedata.datasets.forEach((dataset,i) => (<div key={i}>{findMax(dataset.data)}</div>))

// using React, you'll need to surround the divs in a parent div
return <>{divs}</>
```

Comment: what do you mean by each element ?

Comment: I mean each item of the array.

Comment: It says  "Unexpected keyword 'const'. "